# Get item of c# dictionary by index?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Im working on a project in unity, im using a dictionary to store player information and then assigning a userID int to the players which is what im attempting to make the index position of the players information in the dictionary, but i think im trying to use this system completely wrong. Currently i have this code:

```
public class Players : IComparable<Players> {
public int userID;
public string userName;
public int userHealth;
public GameObject userPlayer;

public Players(int newID,string Name,int Health,GameObject player){
        userID = newID;
        userName = Name; 
        userHealth = Health;
        userPlayer = player;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Players other){
        if(other == null){
            return 1;
        }
        return userID - other.userID;
    }
}
```

to create the Dictionary i use

```
private Dictionary<NetworkPlayer, Players> playerList = new Dictionary<NetworkPlayer,Players>();
```

to add to it i use

`playerList.Add(player,new Players(playerList.Count,"Test", 100, playerObj));`

I was hoping to use the `playerList.Count` part as a method of indexing it and then sorting it by this index to get the player i wanted back... is there a way of doing this correctly? This is my first time attempting to use dictionarys in c# and im finding it hard to understand how they work, if someone could help lead me to a working method of doing this. All i need to be able to do is to return data based off its index OR using the NetworkPlayer class.

If anyone could help lead me to a working method of doing this id be grateful, Thanks.

Comment: [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) maybe?

Comment: You should look at the SortedDictionary class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132289(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter wow i found ordered lists but i didnt know there was an ordered dictionary... thanks that looks perfect! foolish of me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard dictionary's items are not sorted in this way.  Normally, if you want to pull out the player by a specific ID, it would be better to make that the key in the dictionary, ie:

```
private Dictionary<int, Players> playersByID = new Dictionary<int, Players>();
private Dictionary<NetworkPlayer, Players> playersByNetwork = new Dictionary<NetworkPlayer, Players>();
```

Note that you could store two dictionaries, one for each form of lookup:

You could then store:

```
int id = nextID; // Using ID counter...

var newPlayer = new Players(id, "Test", 100, playerObj);
playersById.Add(id, newPlayer);
playersByNetwork.Add(player, newPlayer);
```

And fetch via:

```
var player = playersById[120];
```

Or via:

```
var player = playersByNetwork[netPlayer];
```

---

On a side note: I didn't use the `Count` as an ID, since that will fail if you ever remove players... If that is something you will never do in your system, you could go back to using the `Count` property for your next id.

Comment: But i also need to be able to get the player by the NetworkPlayer class

Comment: @JamesTrotter A common technique is to use two dictionaries, in that case.

Comment: or right i see what you did how foolish of me, yes this method may well work!

Comment: I just have one question, if i update `playersById.userHealth` to a different value, will it be updated in both dictionaries? or just the one? so what im asking is do i need to update both at the same time or would that be redundant?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47802/discussion-between-james-trotter-and-reed-copsey)

Answer (score -1):

You can also index the dictionary values by yourself enveloping the key-value pair you are interested into a KeyValuePair and associating it with an int like so:

```
Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<string, int>> indexedDictionary = new Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<string, int>>
    {
        {0, new KeyValuePair<string, int>("my entry", 13) },
        {1, new KeyValuePair<string, int>("whatever", 5) },
        {............}
    };
```